# Variable classification error while storing structure within parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a function which runs a parfor loop. Within the loop, I call another function which generates a structure as a result. I need to store all the structures.

```
function myFunction(arguments)
    % do some preliminary calcultions
    parfor i = 1:num_sim % number of simulations
        name = sprintf('result_%i',i)
        % do some calculations and generate a structure as a result called "struct_result"
        total_results.(name) = struct_result
    end
end
```

This gives me an error message:

> The variable total_results in a parfor cannot be classified.

How can I store the structure "struct_result" from all the simulations? It is a nested structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assigning to part of `total_results` during the loop, but not in a ["sliced"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/sliced-variable.html) manner. It's probably simpler to collect up the names and values separately, and then use [`cell2struct`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) after the `parfor` loop, like this:

```
N = 10;
names = cell(1, N);
results = cell(1, N);
parfor i = 1:10
    name = sprintf('result_%i',i)
    names{i} = name;
    results{i} = struct('a', rand(i), 'b', rand(i));
end
total_results = cell2struct(results, names, 2);
```

*EDIT* another way of slicing the outputs (as suggested in the comments) is to use

```
parfor i = 1:10
    total_results(i).result = struct('a', rand(i), 'b', rand(i));
end
```

In this case, this works because the first-level indexing expression is a "sliced" expression.

Comment: I made a change, `total_results(i).result = struct_result` and it worked. Is the logic same here?

Comment: Yes, that would work too - but results in an array of `struct`, rather than a scalar struct with multiple fields. That solution is probably more useful...

Comment: Maybe you can add that too to your answer. Thanks for the help.